(C++) How can I make sure that when I do a combo of AND and XOR calculations, the XOR is calculated first?
I'm writing code in C++ that when performing a combo of AND and XOR calculations, I want the XOR to be calculated first.
For example
Binary a1(0x1);
Binary a2(0x2);
Binary a3(0x5);
Binary answer;

answer = a1 & a2 ^ a3;

the output of answer should be 0x8.
However, when I execute the code in progress, resulting in the incorrect value of 0x5.
Binary.h
struct Binary
{
    // ---Skip Constructor---

    struct XOR;
    struct AND;
    struct COMBO;

    XOR operator ^ (const Binary& r) const;
    AND operator & (const Binary& r) const;
    COMBO operator & (const XOR& r) const;

    operator unsigned int() const;

    // Data: (do not add or modify the data)
    unsigned int x;
};

// ---Skip XOR, AND struct---

struct Binary::COMBO
{
    COMBO(const Binary& a, const XOR& b);
    operator Binary() const;
    operator unsigned int() const;

    const Binary& a;
    const XOR& b;
};

Binary.cpp
#include "Binary.h"

// Skip constructor and operator =

Binary::XOR Binary::operator ^ (const Binary& r) const
{
    return XOR(*this, r);
}

Binary::AND Binary::operator & (const Binary& r) const
{
    return AND(*this, r);
}

Binary::COMBO Binary::operator & (const XOR& r) const
{
    return COMBO(*this, r);
}

Binary::operator unsigned int() const
{
    return this->x;
}

Binary::XOR::XOR(const Binary& a, const Binary& b) : a(a), b(b) {}
Binary::XOR::operator Binary() const
{
    return Binary(a.x ^ b.x);
}
Binary::XOR::operator unsigned int() const
{
    return a.x ^ b.x;
}

Binary::AND::AND(const Binary& a, const Binary& b) : a(a), b(b) {}
Binary::AND::operator Binary() const
{
    return Binary(a.x & b.x);
}
Binary::AND::operator unsigned int() const
{
    return a.x & b.x;
}

Binary::COMBO::COMBO(const Binary& a, const XOR& b) : a(a), b(b) {}
Binary::COMBO::operator Binary() const
{
    return Binary(a.x + static_cast<unsigned int>(b));
}
Binary::COMBO::operator unsigned int() const
{
    return a.x + static_cast<unsigned int>(b);
}

No matter how many times I fix it, output is 0x5
and it still calculates a1 & a2 first in a1 & a2 ^ a3.
I think the problem is with the COMBO struct.
I can't even change the test code to a1 & (a2 ^ a3) and I don't know what to do.

& has a higher precedence than ^, so you need a1 & (a2 ^ a3) to do what you want. But why are all of your operators returning different structs at all? They should return Binary objects that hold the new values, see What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?

Does this answer your question? Operator Precedence Overloading in C++

I am working on an assignment where I need to keep the a1 & a2 ^ a3structure of the test code, but only modify the binary to give the same result as a1 & (a2 ^ a3).

You obviously need operator^(AND, Binary) overload.  You only have overloaded operators that take Binary on the left. If you need to handle even more complex expressions, you are looking for a full-on expression template implementation (which could be what your assignment is driving at). Note however that, from overloaded operators alone, it would be impossible to distinguish a1 & a2 ^ a3 and (a1 & a2) ^ a3 - no matter what you do, these two expressions would produce the same result.
